# Reference needed for integration on boundary of Lipschitz domain

Tags: integration, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I need a reference for a definition of an integral of a function $f:\partial\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ over the boundary of a Lipschitz open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (the usual domain in PDEs):
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}fd\sigma = ?$$

I am aware of two definitions: one in Necas' book (which is painful to read) and one in Boyer's book which uses a lot of half-space stuff which I want to avoid.

I would like a definition that uses chart maps back to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ obviously. I have searched a long time but haven't found anything good to cite.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can try this book, chapter 6: http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Function_Spaces.html?id=7WZl50M2SPsC&redir_esc=y

Comment: You are welcome. It helped you?

Comment: Yes it did, it suggessted to me that $C^{0,1}$ domain is too cumbersome to work with because one needs to use a affine transformation of the coordinate system. When manipulating this in the norms it becomes a pain. So I decided to use $C^k$ domain (and learn more about it too).

Comment: However, it is worth to note that in many applications, our domain is only Lipschitz.